# error in session build in a servlet

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

There is a problem in the session. 
In create.html when i click on createdepartment the createdepartment.jsp page opens i copy its url1 after i submit the data , i again copy the url2 and then i logout after logging out when i paste url2 in the browser it gives message that Please login first and opens login.html but when i paste url1 in the browser it opens it but it shouldn't. Why is this happening?
I have given the code please could someone correct it?

LoginServlet.java

```
package bean;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            request.getRequestDispatcher("link.html").include(request, response);


            String name=request.getParameter("name");
            String password=request.getParameter("password");
            boolean status=false;
    try{
        Connection con=ConnectionProvider.getCon();
        String sql="select * from roles where name='" + name + "' and pass='" + password + "'";
        PreparedStatement stmt =con.prepareStatement(sql);
        String role="admin";                        
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next())
        {
            status=true;
            role=rs.getString("role");
        }

         if(status){
        out.print("Welcome, "+name);
        HttpSession session=request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("name",name);
        if(role!=null && role.equals("admin") ){   

        request.getRequestDispatcher("create.html").include(request, response);

        }
        else {

         request.getRequestDispatcher("create1.html").include(request, response);

      }

    }
    else{
        out.print("Sorry, username or password error!");
        request.getRequestDispatcher("login.html").include(request, response);
    }
    }catch( SQLException | ServletException | IOException e){}


        }
}



}
```

create.html

```
<a href="LogoutServlet">Logout</a>
<a href="department.jsp">Create Department</a>
<a href="c_user.jsp">Create Users</a>
<hr/>
```

department.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Create Department</h1>
<br>
<form action="DepartmentServlet">
    <table border="1">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Company Name :</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="company" value="" size="50"    /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Department Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="department" value="" size="50" />  </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Head Office :</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="place" value="" size="50"   /></td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="reset" value="Clear" name="Clear" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit" />

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

DepartmentServlet.java

```
package bean;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;


public class DepartmentServlet extends HttpServlet {



@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
   response.setContentType("text/html");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            request.getRequestDispatcher("link.html").include(request, response);

            HttpSession session=request.getSession(false);
            if(session!=null){
                String name=(String)session.getAttribute("name"); 
                boolean status=false;
    try{
        String department=request.getParameter("department");
        String company=request.getParameter("company");
        String place=request.getParameter("place");

        Connection con=ConnectionProvider.getCon();
        String sql="insert into department(departmentname,company,place) values (?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement pstmt =con.prepareStatement(sql);

        pstmt.setString(1,department); 
        pstmt.setString(2,company);
        pstmt.setString(3,place);

        int rs=pstmt.executeUpdate();
        if(rs>0){status=true;}
    }catch(Exception e){}
              if(status){
                out.print("Values have been inserted,"+name);
                request.getSession();}
              else 
              {
                  out.print("failed");
              }                    
                request.getRequestDispatcher("department.jsp").include(request, response);
            }
            else{
                out.print("Please login first");
                request.getRequestDispatcher("login.html").include(request, response);
            }
        }
    }

    }
```

Logout.Servlet

```
package bean;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
public class LogoutServlet extends HttpServlet {
            @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
                try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
                    request.getRequestDispatcher("link.html").include(request, response);

                    HttpSession session=request.getSession();
                    session.invalidate();

                    out.print("You are successfully logged out!");
                }
}
}
```

Comment: my name is `foo' UNION SELECT 'admin' FROM DUAL --`, maybe you missed the comments in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37699810/comparing-values-while-inserting)

Comment: prepared statement comment??if yes i changed it

Comment: You missed the point of prepared statements, please read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: could you be a little more direct i read it and still seems to be missing the point

Comment: please tell the problem in session also

Comment: the point is to use ? placeholders to avoid issues like there's a `'` in the name etc, using ?, java makes sure nothing nasty is passed to your DB, it's well explained here: http://bobby-tables.com/ (and for your session issue, I don't know)

Comment: ok got it i'll keep this in mind in future

Comment: Those who down voted please tell the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://mytechsoft.jimdo.com/exclusive-projects

> above link is for your problem,  refer first 2 photos in it

Answer (score 0):

LogoutServlet.java code might has problem.

You haven't mentioned its code.

Logout procedure includes 2 important things..

1. Remove all attributes attached to that session object
2. Make session object null (by making session.invalidate(); ) 
   doing this makes session eligible for Garbage Collection, and reference of object (object stored in heap memory) is deleted (reference is stored in stack ).

> In your case, I guess (because LogoutServlet.java is not there), most likely the reason for error is that
>   "***You might be creating a new session Object and then you are copying the reference of old session object, now you would be deleting this new session by "session.invalidate();".***
>
> The above process deletes new reference but old one is still there because it's copy available in new object is deleted not the original one.

**For More Specific and correct answer, please attach your LogoutServlet.java source code too.**

Comment: i don't have a twitter account here is my email id -                                       bawejasushant07@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Your logout servlet should have request.getSession(false)..This will not return new session if one already exists..Also clear your browser cache before running it.

HttpSession session=request.getSession(false);
session.invalidate();